# customizing oracle query results into a table with php

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have this sql query
select count(n.msisdn) FULL_KYC, decile_group
from  Table1

The results I get here are the numbers(FULL_KYC) and decile_group(from decile 1 to decile 10). I need to be able to add this results to a table in php including a new row down for totals of each column. I am using oracle database and connecting remotely.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you need a web server with php and oracle extension for php. Then you can use the oracle connector for Php and launch the query, retrieve data and show them with an html table.

Here is an example: http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.examples.php.

Bye

For accomplish the complete request you can change

```
print "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    print "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        print "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
    print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
```

in

```
    print "<table border='1'>\n";
$finalRow = array();
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    print "<tr>\n";

    foreach ($row as $key => $item) {
        $finalRow[$key] = (isset($finalRow[$key]) ? $finalRow[$key] : 0) + $item;
        print "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
    print "</tr>\n";
}

print "<tr>\n";

foreach ($finalRow as $item) {
      print "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
}
print "</tr>\n";

print "</table>\n";
```

Comment: Thank mate. the only prob is that the query results will be in the table exactly as they are. yt i need totals for all columns and some other basic aggregates calculated using query results.

Comment: Thanks alot. Great help here.